# Merging dictionaries in C# such that common keys are present

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> testDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            testDict.Add("Name", "John");
            testDict.Add("City", "NY");

Dictionary<string, string> DictA = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            DictA.Add("Name", "Sarah");
            DictA.Add("State", "ON");
```

I wish to get a Dictionary such that only such tuples of DictA are present which have the same key as in testDict

So the example merged dictionary should look as below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> DictMerged = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                DictMerged.Add("Name", "Sarah");
```

I hope I have been able to explain my requirements..

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I believe one of the reasons that you're getting downvotes is because you haven't shown what you have tried. It is very important that you do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way :

```
var DictMerged = DictA.Where(o => testDict.ContainsKey(o.Key))
                      .ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cRA2ZT)</kbd>**

The codes above simply filter itmes in `DictA` where the item key exists in `testDict` keys, and then project the result into a new dictionary instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `LINQ`:

```
var resultDict = testDict.Keys.Intersect(DictA.Keys)
   .ToDictionary(t => t, t => DictA[t]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a join between the two dictionaries.  Something like this (typed in here, so it might be off a little):

```
dictA
    .Join(testDict, kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Key, (kva, kvt) => kva)
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)
```

This does a Join like in a database between two tables.  The second and third arguments are saying that you want to join on the Key of each dictionary (same treatment for each side).  The final argument says "for each match, select the key-value item from DictA (and discard the one from testDict)" and finally convert the sequence of KeyValuePairs that pop out back into dictionary form.